# CalendarView returns always current day ignoring what user selects

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile, android-studio

There is a CalendarView in screen and I want to display the selected date on the same screen. I want it to change dynamically as user changes the selected date.

This works perfect in my phone LG G2. Whenever I select a date in calendar, it shows that date. But in Nexus 10 tablet whatever date I select, it returns the current day. And if I keep changing the date, nothing changes it always display the current day.

Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, container, false);
    calendarView = (CalendarView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    selectedDate = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
            date = new Date(calendarView.getDate());
            dateString = simpleDate.format(date);
            MainActivity.selectedDate=dateString;
            selectedDate.setText(dateString);
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? What may be reason that CalendarView acts different in phone and tablet? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on devices with Lollipop. The only thing I could think of was working with a `Calendar` within the `onSelectedDayChange`

```
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    Date d = c.getTime; // here is your correct date
}
```